# How to make this function with parameters that are variables return a list?

Tags: python, function, loops, variables

I edited this since someone helped me with the main issue, but for some reason I can't get this thing to print me out the list of the sequence, and I can't figure out why, but I think my validation might be wrong.

```
import math

while True:
    startVal = (input('Enter the starting value: '))
    maxVal = (input('Enter the maximum value:'))
    try:
        startVal = float(startVal)
        maxVal = float(maxVal)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('False')

def number_sequence(startVal, maxVal):
    j = startVal
    sequence = [startVal]

    while j <= maxVal:
        i = (math.sqrt((j + 4) ** 3)) + 5.125936194710044
        i = round(i, 3)   
        if j <= maxVal:
            sequence.append(i)
        j = i
    return sequence
```

Comment: I didn't understand what it should do but probably you need a loop (`while`, I guess).

Comment: What is the point of calculating `i = (math.sqrt((j + 4)**3)) + 5.125936194710044` and `i = round(i, 3)` when you throw those values away on the very next line by assigning `i = j` ?

Comment: It unclear what kind of sequence you need to generate.

Comment: What does your **call** to `number_sequence` look like?

Comment: You never call *number_sequence()*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `number_sequence` function before the while loop
and you need to call the function. Your code is not calling.

Try below code:

```py
import math 
def number_sequence(startVal, maxVal):
    j = startVal
    sequence = []
    while j <= maxVal:
        i = (math.sqrt((j + 4) ** 3)) + 5.125936194710044
        i = round(i, 3)
        if j <= maxVal:
            sequence.append(i)
        j = i
    return sequence


while True: 
    startVal = (input('Enter the starting value: ')) 
    maxVal = (input('Enter the maximum value:')) 
    try: 
        startVal = float(startVal) 
        maxVal = float(maxVal) 
    except ValueError: 
        print('False') 
    # when ValueError occurs, if you want to prompt user again
    # use continue instead of break
        break #continue

    retuned_sequence = number_sequence(startVal, maxVal)
    print(retuned_sequence)
    break
```

Comment: just `return [startVal] if startVal <=maxVal else []` is enough. No need of appending

Comment: I am clarifying OP's question, not answering yet.

Comment: you just posted it as an answer. consider commenting rather

Comment: i want to output a list of numbers that go through this caluculation: (math.sqrt((j + 4)**3)) + 5.125936194710044.  the startVal is the first number in the list, and after it goes through the calculation the new number is also added to the list and then reput into the calculation to find another number that keeps getting added to the list until it reaches a number less or equal to the max parameter

Comment: @inversedawn I edited the answer. If (0.1, 20.86) is given, based on your formula it returns [0.1, 13.428, 77.882]. Is it what you wanted ?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i wanted!! but for some reason when i try printing it nothing is being returned still in my terminal. idk if there is something wrong with my overall code.

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, I would like to comment, but for that 50 reputation points is required, which I don't have. But based on OP's comments, I changed it to a "real" answer.

Comment: @inversedawn, you need to import math module. How are you calling it and printing it? Can you share your code

Comment: i already have it in the start of my code which is this:                 import math

while True:
    startVal = (input('Enter the starting value: '))
    maxVal = (input('Enter the maximum value:'))
    try:
        startVal = float(startVal)
        maxVal = float(maxVal)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('False')

def number_sequence(startVal, maxVal):
    j = startVal
    sequence = [startVal]

Comment: @inversedawn  updated the answer, replace your code with above. It should work.

Comment: thank you so much u are a G. one more question... do i have to use the print function in order to see the actual sequence. i thought once i told the function to return the sequence to me i would be able to see it. i didn't know i had to print it out?

Comment: @inversedawn yes, you need to print it.

Comment: @inversedawn if it answered your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to import math to get the code to work in my python.
and 5 and 300 were random values I chose.
*****Hujaakbar code is solid*****____

```
import math

def number_sequence(startVal, maxVal):
    j = startVal
    sequence = [startVal]
    while j <= maxVal:
        i = (math.sqrt((j + 4) ** 3)) + 5.125936194710044
        i = round(i, 3)   
        if j <= maxVal:
            sequence.append(i)
        j = i
    return sequence


print(number_sequence(5,300))
```

Comment: sorry if this is stupid, but do i have to use the print function in order for the sequence to return the list? i can't just use return function?

Comment: The function is going to do just what you tell it. To see the output I believe the print function is necessary. I am new learning too. I have only "called a function" to see an output using print, but you can call the function for whatever you want ie: to return it as a new variable for somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I just took out the print function and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the OP doesn't output anything is because there's no code that would do that (except for the input validation and possible ValueError).

You need to arrange for *number_sequence()* to return something and then print that.

The calculation in *number_sequence()* can easily be written as a "one-liner" but that can make things hard to read, understand and maintain. Better to break the steps one by one.

There's a point in the calculation where you raise a value to the power of 3 then immediately take its square root. To achieve that, just raise to the power of 1.5.

```
def number_sequence(startVal, maxVal):
    sequence = [startVal]

    while (j := sequence[-1]) <= maxVal:
        j += 4
        j **= 1.5
        j += 5.125936194710044
        sequence.append(round(j, 3))

    return sequence

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        startVal = input('Enter the starting value: ')
        maxVal = input('Enter the maximum value: ')
        try:
            startVal = float(startVal)
            maxVal = float(maxVal)
            print(number_sequence(startVal, maxVal))
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
```